# Is the torus a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, dynamical-systems

Is the $n$-torus $T^{n} := \mathbb{R}^{n} / \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ a metric space with Euclidean metric? Or perhaps some other metric? Can you provide a book or paper to this so I can read about it?

Comment: It is a metric space with a variety of metrics, one coming from embedding it into 3D space (e.g. by rotating a vertical circle around $z$-axis), and another from making it flat, see [flat torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus).

Comment: You might enjoy this book: [The Shape of Space.](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Shape_of_Space.html?id=x3DKDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description)

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the recommendation. I read chapter 1 and it captured my attention because of the intuitive way it introduces manifolds and the writing style is very beautiful too. Also in two month I will be starting a course in differential geometry which I suppose studies manifolds in higher dimensions? So this comes at a good time in my studies. Thank you!

Comment: @Conifold So what is the "standard" metric on the torus? I.e. on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ it would be the Euclidean metric.

Comment: There is no "standard", but the flat metric is locally Euclidean.